# How to redirect a page with a parameter to its normal version?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So plain and simple, I have quite a few pages that are being recognised by Google that I don't want.

For example:

```
www.mydomain.com.au/page.html?wvsessionid=wv0ca063bc7d214c95845f0b751c201fd8
www.mydomain.com.au/anotherpage.html?wvsessionid=qertq451514361456
```

I would like to be able to redirect all these pages to ones without the paramaters. For example, using the two links above, they would go to:

```
www.mydomain.com.au/page.html
www.mydomain.com.au/anotherpage.html
```

Currently, I have all pages with `wvsessionid=` within them going directly to my 404 page using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com\.au [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)wvsessionid=
RewriteRule !^/404.html - [L,R=404]
```

Very new to mod-rewrite and htaccess.

How could I modify my code direct the pages to their simple form, instead of my 404 page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com\.au [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)wvsessionid=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks! Haha, you helped write the original one, and now this one. Champion!